# Is Latent Semantic Analysis a clustering algorithm?

Tags: k-means, latent-semantic-indexing

The input of LSA is a term frequency matrix of a set of documents. What's the output? If I want to cluster a bunch of news into different clusters, can I use LSA? If not, what's the major uses of LSA?

Is it similar to K-means?

Comment: Of possible help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143547/how-are-the-clustering-algorithms-using-the-concept-of-latent-semantic-analysis?rq=1